# Check if value exists within an array of objects

Tags: php

I am working on an API which receives a PHP object of `$POST` data. I am trying to check wether the 'smsPhoneNumber' inside customFields exists but not sure how to do this.

I am currently able to check for 'email' using:

```
if ( property_exists( $data, 'email' ) ) {
  return true;
}
```

**Question:** How to check if 'smsPhoneNumber' exists?

--

*var_dump:*

```
object(stdClass)[1515]
  public 'email' => string 'email@email.com'
  public 'customFields' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[1512]
          public 'name' => string 'Firstname'
          public 'value' => string 'james' 
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[1514]
          public 'name' => string 'smsPhoneNumber'
          public 'value' => string '077'
```

Comment: Is this json decoded data?

Comment: simplest way is do a foreach on `$yourobj->customFields` and check required property

Comment: Ya know, there is a second parameter in `json_decode()` .. look it up

Comment: @tereško, I mean, you could convert this to an array but it wouldn't change much about how you'd have to access these custom fields.

Comment: yeh it would be a bit easier if the objects in customFields were arrays, but a `foreach` iteration is likely your best solution regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array_filter to get the custom field you want.

```
$phoneFields = array_filter($data->customFields, function($field) {
    return $field->name === 'smsPhoneNumber';
});
```

This will only return objects in the array that have a name property equal to smsPhoneNumber.

```
if (!count($phoneFields)) {
    // Phone not found
}

// or

if ($phone = current($phoneFields)) {
    echo "The first phone number found is " . $phone->value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The drawback of using `array_filter()` to search for the subarray values is:

- `array_filter()` will not stop once it finds a match; it will keep iterating even after a match is found until it reaches the end of the array.

You should use a technique that allows an early `break`/`return`.

I recommend a simple `foreach()` with a `break`.

```
$foundIndex = null;
foreach ($data->customFields as $index => $customFields) {
    if ($customFields->name === 'smsPhoneNumber') {
        $foundIndex = $index;
        // or $wasFound = true;
        // or $smsNumber = $customFields->value;
        break;
    }
}
```

This will prove to be very efficient and easy to read/maintain.